# Why numpy.double applies to a nested list and numpy.complex doesn't?

Tags: python, numpy

Why numpy.double applies to a nested list element by element and numpy.complex doesn't?

Example follows.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> L = [['1','2'],['2','3']]
>>> print numpy.double( L )
[[ 1.  2.]
 [ 2.  3.]]
>>> print numpy.complex( L )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "avr_std.py", line 17, in <module>
    print np.complex( L )
TypeError: complex() argument must be a string or a number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.float` and `np.complex` are the usual non-vectorized Python versions:

```
>>> np.float is float
True
>>> np.complex is complex
True
```

It's the `numpy`-specific ones which can deal with non-scalar inputs:

```
>>> np.float_([1,2])
array([ 1.,  2.])
>>> np.double is np.float_
True
>>> np.complex_([1,2])
array([ 1.+0.j,  2.+0.j])
>>> np.float32([1,2])
array([ 1.,  2.], dtype=float32)
>>> np.complex192([1,2])
array([ 1.0+0.0j,  2.0+0.0j], dtype=complex192)
```

and so on.

Comment: thank you! np.complex_([1,2]) does work for me, but np.complex_(['1','2']) doesn't. np.float_ worked in both cases. And, could you please let me know how did you learn it - I mean, what should I read to answer this kind of questions myself?

Comment: Do you need to start with lists of strings?  If I need to make small sample arrays I use something like `np.array([1,2,3])` or `np.array([[1+3j, 4-4j],[3,4]])`.  `np.matrix('1 2 3;4 5 6+1j')` is nice if you want MATLAB like input.  `np.complex` is better used as a `dtype` value than as a function. `np.array([[1,2],[3,5]],dtype=np.complex)`.

Comment: It's indeed better practice to user `np.array([...], dtype=complex)` than to rely on `np.complex_` functioning as an array constructor.